# Who conducted the new music in Runescape?

Tags: runescape

What band or orchestra conducted or created the newest music for Runescape 2013? What other music tracks have they done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The music is composed by [James Hannigan](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0360430/?ref_=fn_al_nm_1), who has composed music for many games, including Command & Conquer: Red Alert 3 and the Harry Potter games.

It was conducted by [Allan Wilson](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0932977) and performed by the [Slovak National Symphony Orchestra](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm4038412) in Bratislava, Slovakia.